# Prove derivative with summation by induction

Tags: derivatives, summation, proof-writing, binomial-theorem

I have this math question. That I am stuck on.

> If $f$ is a function, let $Df$ be its derivative.  For $n\in
>  \mathbb{Z}^+$ let $$ f^{(n)} = \underbrace{D \cdots D }_{n\mathrm{\
>  times}} f $$ be the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative of $f$.  In this
>    notation the usual product rule from calculus  says that   $$
>  (fg)^{(1)} = fg^{(1)} + f^{(1)} g. $$ Using the product rule, prove
>    the formula for the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative of a product  $$
>  (fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}. $$ (Hint: 
>    The proof in here is similar to the proof of the Binomial Theorem.)

Here's my work for it so far:

$$(fg)^{(1)} = \sum_{k=0}^{1}\binom{1}{k}f^{(1-k)}g^k=f^{(1)}g^{(0)}+f^{(0)}g^{(1)}$$

We assume $P(m)$ is true (induction assumption):

$$(fg)^{(m)}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}f^{(m-k)}g^k$$

We want to show that $P(m+1)$ is also true:

$$(fg)^{(m+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k}f^{(m+1-k)}g^k$$

I'm not sure how to connect the induction assumption with $P(m+1)$ thanks.

Comment: Well, have you tried your hint? I.e. do you know the proof of the binomial theorem?

Comment: Have you even tried? What do you get if you try to calculate $(fg)^{(m+1)} = D((fg)^{(m)}) = D\sum...$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Observe that

$$D\left[{m\choose k}f^{(m-k)}g^{(k)}\right]={m \choose k}f^{(m-k)}g^{(k+1)}+{m \choose k}f^{(m-k+1)}g^{(k)}$$
And use the identity
$${n \choose r}+{n \choose r+1}={n+1 \choose r+1}.$$